# DiscretePlot - adjusting the scale on Y axis to log with prescribed spacing

Tags: plotting

I have this picture of a residual `Plot` I am trying to reproduce (`Y` axis scale should be the same as in my plot):

[image: Reference graph]

The code I have used is:

```
DiscretePlot[ResN[[i]], {i, 1, 10}, Joined -> True, Filling -> None, 
     PlotMarkers -> "Point", PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, 1}}, 
     PlotLabel -> "Res(n)"]`
```

[image: Plot with the Y-axis to be modified to agree with upper graph]

`ResN` is a `List` with values for ten columns.

Any help would be appreciated. I browsed around for the answer, but without any success.

Comment: Have you seen `ListLogPlot`?

Comment: @NJEvans: Yes, I have, but it is not working in my case, because 'ResN' is not a rule ar a list of rules. Sektor: thank you for edit!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myRes[n_] := 1/n^3;
myFig = ListLogPlot[Table[{n, myRes[n]}, {n, 1, 10}],
  PlotLabel -> Text[Style["Res(n)", 18]],
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {10^(-8), 100}},
  Joined -> True,
  Ticks -> {Automatic, 
    Table[{10^i, "1. E " <> ToString[i]}, {i, -8, 2, 2} ]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Your comment was very valuable. However, I had to change the definition of my ResN variable to be a List type. I made this with the use of Range. Now I can use ListLogPlot to plot the data. How could I modify your plot to have a value of 1 plotted at the 0 value of the abscisa axis (not at 1 as in thisa case)?

Comment: Solved the problem with setting PlotMarkers-->Automatic.

Comment: @Mike `Res[n_] := 1/(n+1)^3` and `Table[..., {n, 0, 10}]`.